# google.load and google apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sites, jsapi

I'm trying to add visualizations to a google site using google apps script, but I keep getting a syntax error for file 'code' despite having copied it directly from the developers page for google charts.  The code is below.  it's the line 
 google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['motionchart']});
that keeps breaking.  I'm assuming it's not finding the library, but I can't figure out how to fix it.  Can I not use this in apps script?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['motionchart']});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Fruit');
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Sales');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Expenses');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Location');
        data.addRows([
          ['Apples',  new Date (1988,0,1), 1000, 300, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1988,0,1), 1150, 200, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1988,0,1), 300,  250, 'West'],
          ['Apples',  new Date (1989,6,1), 1200, 400, 'East'],
          ['Oranges', new Date (1989,6,1), 750,  150, 'West'],
          ['Bananas', new Date (1989,6,1), 788,  617, 'West']
        ]);
        var chart = new 

google.visualization.MotionChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 600, height:300});
          }
        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 300px;"></div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You cant use those libraries in apps script because of caja-related issues. If you look at the apps script issues page you will see more info as there is an issue logged there. See https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2949

Answer (score 0):

This example does work these days.

It looks like it was gradually rolled out sometime after mid-March, based upon what was said in [Google Apps Unscripted - March 2014](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/5678163715686400) around minute 50.